# Changing Dynamic Text with Hit Test

Tags: flash, variables, actionscript-2, dynamic-text

I'm making a flash game and want to update the lap number using a line at the start of each lap, i have a dynamic text box which is set at run time to say lap '0 of 3' - That works fine.

```
var p1:String = "0 of 3";
lapPlayer1.text = p1;
```

Each time the car hits a line with the instance name **LapChange** I want it to update, i have put a hit test on the car. Text Box is Dynamic Classic and it called **lapPlayer1**

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame){

if(this.hitTest(_root.LapChange)){

if (lapPlayer1.text == "0 of 3") {

        var p1:String = "1 of 3";
        lapPlayer1.text = p1;
    }

    if (lapPlayer1.text == "1 of 3") {

        var p1:String = "1 of 3";
        lapPlayer1.text = p1;

    } 

    if (lapPlayer1.text == "2 of 3") {

        var p1:String = "3 of 3";
        lapPlayer1.text = p1;
    }
}
}
```

However it isn't updating the text, any help would be appreciated

Carl

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general idea:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,update){
    if(car.hitTestObject(line)){
        laps++;
    }

    switch(laps){
    case 1:
    your_text.text="lap one of three";
    break;
    //etc
    }
}
```

Use the switch block to easily find the match and change the textfield accordingly

Comment: I just realized that you're using the dreaded AS2. You'll have to adapt the code to your version.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `lapPlayer1` located? Surely it isn't inside the car, right?

You have to target `lapPlayer1` from inside the car, since that's where your code is, and assuming it's placed on `_root`, change your code to this:

```
onClipEvent(enterFrame){

if(this.hitTest(_root.LapChange)){

if (_root.lapPlayer1.text == "0 of 3") {

        var p1:String = "1 of 3";
        _root.lapPlayer1.text = p1;
    }

    if (_root.lapPlayer1.text == "1 of 3") {

        var p1:String = "1 of 3";
        _root.lapPlayer1.text = p1;

    } 

    if (_root.lapPlayer1.text == "2 of 3") {

        var p1:String = "3 of 3";
        _root.lapPlayer1.text = p1;
    }
}
}
```